# SSH access on openstack nodes

Tags: linux, openstack

I have setup openstack using 2 nodes with Mirantis Fuel.

After openstack gets deployed, I am unable to access the controller node and compute node via SSH as authentication fails when I try to access them.

Where do I find the private key to access the node via ssh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't now about MiFuel, but in the standard Openstack you download the keys from the Horizon Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to access the node server not an instance,
so Dashboard won't help cause the key from it is used to access instances not the whole server.

In linux you can find the ssh keys in

```
~/.ssh/
```

Here you can find the public and the private key.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're attempting to ssh in as a user other than root.  Logging in via ssh using the default 'root' password has worked for me on Fuel 5.0 - 6.1.

You may also consider to ssh via the fuel node, too.